# How many times an NBA team has won at least 3 consecutive overtime games?

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba

The LA Lakers won three consecutive overtime games from February 6th-10th, 2021, beating the Pistons, the Thunder, and the Thunder again.

How many times since [the 1976 merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA%E2%80%93NBA_merger) has an NBA team won three or more consecutive games in overtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time I could find after 2000 was the [2007 Minnesota Timberwolves](https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/MIN/2007_games.html), Featuring Kevin Garnett, who won three overtime games in a row Jan. 3 through Jan. 7, against San Antonio (Featuring Tim Duncan), Philadelphia (Featuring Allan Iverson), and Houston (Featuring Yao Ming and Tracy McGrady).

Going further back, I see the [1987 Phoenix Suns](https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/PHO/1987_games.html), Featuring Larry Nance, who more impressively won three OT games *in four nights*, April 4-7, 1987, against the Clippers, Mavericks, and (then-Seattle) Supersonics. (None of which were really very good or had any major stars that I recall, though the Mavericks and the Supersonics made the playoffs, and the 'Sonics did go to the Western Finals before running into Magic and Company.  I guess Dale Ellis and Nate McMillan were good enough?)

I'm a bit less confident in the older years, as BBRef standings do seem to change a bit, but this seems to be comprehensive from the 1970-2021 period from what my scraping could tell.  I think if you have a subscription to whatever it is that underlies Basketball Reference nowadays, you could run this search directly.

I put some code [here](https://github.com/snoopy369/Sports.SE/blob/master/OTW_Streaks_BskBllRef.py), though I didn't really come up with a good way to get 3 in a row - instead I identified 2 in a row consistently, and just checked on those.  2 in a row was pretty rare before the last few years for some reason, so it was easy enough to just check all of them.